# 'checkpermission' issue with get location

Tags: android, permissions, get, location

I'm new Android developer and for start I'm trying to access the location of the phone

I did `checkselfpermission` but it's didn't help, it's still not compile to me

### Self Check permission

Here I'm check if there is permission, if not I ask for it :

```
protected void getLocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }
}
```

### After got permisson

Here I'm trying to access the location but there is exception in the line:
`location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);` :

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION:
                {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // Get the location manager
                        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
                        // default
                        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                        onLocationChanged(location);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location recived.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Can't track your location.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                }
```

I will appreciate any help from you guys

Comment: does it return null?

Answer (score 0):

Have you written these permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've declared `permissions` in `manifest` file -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**as well your have to check runtime permission for both as well.**